# Texture doesn't look the same in the render as the preview render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing

The problem I have is that the texture I have included in my model is displayed correctly in the preview render, but it doesn't correctly work in the final render image. I am using the Cycles render engine.

The screenshots I have below explain my problem:

[image]

[image]

What is the reason for this?
How can I make this work properly. Please if you can help me with it will be a great pleasure. Thank you.

Comment: Has your model multiple UV Maps?

Comment: Are there any duplicated meshes? Looks like some kind of z-fighting to me.